# Call/Execute JQuery function after successful form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, getresponse

I'm using GetResponse web form and I need to popup a fancybox window after successful form submission?

Here is code segment of GetResponse web form

```
<form id="gold_ira_form" accept-charset="utf-8" action="https://app.getresponse.com/add_contact_webform.html?u=bPSV"
                            method="post">

//form code goes here....

<input type="submit" id="submit-btn" value="submit"></input>
</form>
```

Here is my JQuery code:

```
   <script>
            $(function() {
                $('#gold_ira_form').submit(function() {
                    // will be replaced with fancy box code 
                    alert('Sent! show fancybox');

                });
            });
        </script>
```

The above code does not execute the alert after successful form submission.

Is there any alternate to execute jquery function after successful form submission?

Comment: `.submit` callback function will execute once the `.submit` is triggered, *not* after form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you submit a form it automatically refresh the page (or it will redirect to the "action" attribute value page). In order to solve this i would recommend trying to submit your form via ajax :

```
$('#gold_ira_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Ajax code goes here, on ajax complete call fancybox
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
   <script>
        $('document').ready(function() {
            $('#gold_ira_form').submit(function() {

                alert('Sent! show fancybox');
                return false;

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question?